# docker vim inside container gibberish

Tags: docker, vim, containers, dockerfile, vi

from some reason when I'm doing `vim` inside my container I can see and edit my file but when I'm pressing  <kbd>↓</kbd> or <kbd>↑</kbd> or any other buttons I'm getting gibberish
for example:

```
root@a43bb769ffa2:~# vim test.txt 
,1
Top
10,1 
1,0-1 2,1 
20 
2,0-1 3,1 
6,0-1 7,1 
30 
5,0-1 6,1 40
```

any idea why?

I already tried to configure the `environment variables`:

```
LINES=67
COLUMNS=246
TERM=xterm
```

But it didn't help. even after trying to change the number of lines or columns.

my command to enter my container is: `docker exec -it my_container bash`

Comment: How do you access your container?

Comment: with this command: `docker exec -it my_container bash`

Comment: Add `set nocompatible` to your containers's `~/.vimrc` file.

Comment: `:set nocompatible` inside vim didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to `LINES` and `COLUMNS`.
The only way I have found to work with vim inside container is to change the parameters above to:

`LINES=40
COLUMNS=160`

yes in some screens resolution it will appear has half screen but it's the only way the I have found to workaround my issue. hopefully that this thing will have better solution